# How to correctly map MySQL database to Weka values?

Tags: java, mysql, weka

I have a database that I use to generates instances for my Weka machine learning approach:

```
query.setQuery(String.format(SQL_QUERY, selectPartBuilder(tableName), tableName));
Instances instances = query.retrieveInstances();
```

This works fine, but the problem is that some of the values are interpreted as nominal, even though they should be numeric. I had a look at the original data and I don't now why. Since Weka does not offer a NominalToNumeric filter, I don't know what to do next. I also looked at the DatabaseUtils.props file and I think the mapping is correct. What am I missing?

I'm quite sure that the mapping is the problem, because when I use a CSV file with the exactly the same values, the values are correctly interpreted as numeric.
    bit=1
    tinyint=1
    bool=1
    boolean=1
    smallint=5
    mediumint=5
    int=5
    integer=5
    bigint=7
    double=2
    double_precision=2
    float=2
    int(11)=5